# How to prevent reordering on 1 list in jquery ui draggable connect list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am following this example:

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/
connect lists version

I want to be able to drag items from 1 list to the other and vice versa.

However in the 2nd list, I want to reorder items vertically, **BUT** I want to disable this vertical reordering on the first list. However in the example, it allows this sorting on both lists.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Per: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Please include an example of your current code. You may want to us jsfiddle. Include what you have tried so far.